# How to list all languages that are loaded by angular-translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't find it in docs or api of [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/). How can I retrieve all loaded languages by angular translate?

Assuming I have a LanguageCtrl like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('LanguageCtrl', ['$translate', '$scope',
    function ($translate, $scope) {
        $scope.switchLang = function (lang) {
            $translate.use(lang);
        };
        $scope.currentLang = function () {
            return  $translate.use();
        };
        $scope.isCurrentLang = function (lang) {
            return  $translate.use() === lang;
        };
        $scope.languages = function(){
            return $translate.IS_THERE_AN_API_FUNCTION_TO_GET_ALL_LANGUAGES();
        }
    }]);
```

And I load these languages:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['pascalprecht.translate'])
.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('de', de);
    $translateProvider.translations('fr', fr);
    $translateProvider.translations('en', en);
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

Now I would like to display all languages:

```
<ul ng-controller="LanguageCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="lang in languages" ng-class="{active: isCurrentLang(lang)}">
            <a href="" ng-click="switchLang(lang)">lang</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: From what I see in their code you can just call `$translateProvider.transations()` without any arguments and you will get the `$translationTable` returned back to you.  If this works, let me know and I can make it an answer

Comment: thanks @JoseM! i will try this tommorrow. so injecting a provider into a controller does not cause any trouble in angularjs, does it? i am just used to use them in config at startup.

Comment: I think you may not be able to inject the provider in your controller.  I was trying to do some quick research on that but I haven't found anything definitive yet.

Comment: Has any one found out how to get a reference to the translation table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated answer:

```
/**
* @description
* This function simply returns the registered language keys being defined before in the config phase
* With this, an application can use the array to provide a language selection dropdown or similar
* without any additional effort
*
* @returns {object} returns the list of possibly registered language keys and mapping or null if not defined
*/

    $translate.getAvailableLanguageKeys();

/*
* To register language keys, use the following function in your configuration:
*/

    $translateProvider.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'de']);
```

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately there's no API yet to get all registered languages. So in short: this is not possible **yet**.

If you want to, you can open an issue on github to propose that feature. However, keep in mind that when using asynchronous loaders, languages are **not** registered until they are loaded.

Comment: created ab issue as you suggested [https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/566](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/566)

Comment: Any news on this? I want to display the list of languages in my view